# Totally disconnect space and the real number set with lower limit topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Is $\mathbb R_l$ totally disconnected?
We know  $\mathbb R_l $ is finer than  $\mathbb R$ and intervals and one point sets are only connected subsets of   $\mathbb R$ .hence only possible connected sets in  $\mathbb R_l$ is intervals and one point set .as intervals are seperated by $(-\infty ,a),[a,\infty)$ in  $\mathbb R_l$.   Therefore one  point sets are only connected sets in  $\mathbb R_l$.

Am I wrong?

Comment: It seems fine to me.

Comment: Correct. The Sorgenfrey line has a base (basis) of open-and-closed sets.

Answer (score 2):

Direct proof.  If distinct a,b in connected K then, wlog
a < b and (-oo,b), [b,oo) disconnects K by two open sets.